# angular-pickadate timezone - selectedDate is one day before from modal date for other timezones

Tags: angularjs, datetime, timezone

angular-pickadate works for my local time. To check global Times, I have changed my time zone to "America/Denver". Now selected date is taken one day before today's date (passed modal date), so it applies "pickadate-active" class to yesterday.
I tried passing modal date with local timezone and also with UTC timezone. I don't know why dateHelper.parseDate calls again with stripping Timezone value earlier passed, now my understanding is $locale is converting stripped date assuming it a UTC date to local date. Hence, being GMT-06:00, selected date comes to one date before.

HTML DIV - `<div pickadate ng-model="vm.date" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 0 }" header="true" select="true" date-highlight-list="vm.dateList" ></div>`

Controller - `vm.date = moment().tz(timeZoneName).format();`

can someone suggest a way to handle different timezones with angular-pickadate?? Thanks ! 
GIT directive URL - https://github.com/restorando/angular-pickadate

Comment: facing the same issue,did u find any solution

Comment: this question does not belong under angular. use angularjs instead

Comment: ya corrected it,thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parseDate function was giving date object as per GMT timezone, so date was becoming one day less.So I removed this condition which was directly returning GMT date for passed date strings with timezone.

```
if (angular.isDate(dateString) || angular.isDate(new Date(dateString))) {
new Date(dateString); }
```

Now it goes to next if block to format date with regex and added this condition there to handle date strings and date objects -

```
if(typeof dateString == 'object') {
  dateString = (dateString['_d'])? dateString['_d']: dateString['_i'];  // being private (_d, _i) should be avoided but only way in mine case
  if(typeof dateString == 'object')  // returns Object by dateString['_d'] else string 
    dateString = dateString.getDate() +'-'+ dateString.getMonth() +'-' +dateString.getFullYear(); 
}

dateParts   = dateString.split(separator); // separator was "-" every time so making dateString with "-" in case it was object
```